# Flutter: How to create tabbar with navigator without using tabbar view?

Tags: flutter, tabbar, navigator

Currently, I have a calendar page that has a default tab bar that can switch from a month and year calendar using a tab bar view. For the bottom Tab bar, I want it to switch from different pages to for example like a home page. Any ideas? I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user TabController  for create tabBar in fluter. I found a simple [example](https://www.developerlibs.com/2018/06/flutter-tab-bar-controller-and-left.html) of TabBar demo with left Drawer.